# angular datatables not being rendered properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

i am trying to use angular datatables with my angular js project but it seems something is being missed , can someone please help me out

links : -

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.util.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.factory.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.options.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.renderer.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.directive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.instances.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/widget/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.js"></script>
```

html code :-

```
<table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

js code :-

```
var dtJson = [{
            "id": 860,
            "firstName": "Superman",
            "lastName": "Yoda"
        }, {
            "id": 870,
            "firstName": "Foo",
            "lastName": "Whateveryournameis"
        }, {
            "id": 590,
            "firstName": "Toto",
            "lastName": "Titi"
        }];

    $scope.RecordMasterModel.gridData = dtJson;
    $scope.dtInstance = {};
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(dtJson).withPaginationType('full_numbers');

    $scope.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name'),
    ];
```

page after rendering : -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `gridData` is something you have picked up from angular smartTables or angular UI Grid? Also, `fromSource()` means an AJAX source - typically a file like `data.json`, remote or locally. Here is the steps to achieve what you want :

markup :

```
<table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"></table>
```

script :

```
$scope.dtColumns = [
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id', 'ID'),
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName', 'First name'),
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName', 'Last name')
];  
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('data', dtJson)    
  .withDataProp('');
```

The most important part is `.withOption('data', dtJson)` where you push the `dtJson` variable into dataTables native `data` attribute.

now the code works -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNKMNYv9uXKCGKSOyo1y?p=preview**